# What is the difference between attributesToArray() and toArray() in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Can someone explain the difference between `$model->attributesToArray()` and `$model->toArray()` on a model?

I have an issue where a seeder is throwing an error about `getCreatedAtAttribute` method is not defined and it's complaining due to a `toArray()` method call. This is what prompted me to try and find out the difference between the two.

After switching to `attributesToArray()` the seeder runs fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`attributesToArray`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L85) will only fetch the attributes for the current model.

[`toArray`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1036) calls the `attributesToArray` function, but also adds loaded relations to the array.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why `toArray()` would throw a method not found getCreatedAtAttribute, but `attributesToArray()` doesn't?

Comment: If `created_at` is inside the `$appends` array on the model.